# Mousetrap bind won't work in a nuxt.js page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, mousetrap

hi i hope somebody can help me. I want to redirect to a different page as soon as a certain sequence is typed.
I get the "It works" in my console but it won't redirect. I get the error message

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> '$router')"

Here is my code

```html
<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {
          src: "js/mousetrap.min.js",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  components: {},
  name: "IndexPage",
  mounted() {
    Mousetrap.bind("1 2", function () {
      console.log("It works");
      this.$router.push("/pagename");
      return;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

I use the Mousetrap library from https://craig.is/killing/mice btw.

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: The value of `this` inside your callback is clearly not what you expect it to be.

Comment: As stated above, you should use an arrow function to keep `this` as the Vue instance. Also, do not import that with a CDN but rather with an NPM package. Otherwise, you probably want a global listener so putting that into the default layout could be nice too.

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!!! This did the trick for me. Changed it to an arrow function so 'this.$router' can be kept as vue instance.

```
mounted() {
    Mousetrap.bind("1 2", () => {
      this.$router.push("/pagename");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using it like this solved OP's issue:

```js
mounted() {
    Mousetrap.bind("1 2", () => {
      this.$router.push("/pagename");
    });
  }
```